# Searching a custom tableviewCell

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, uisearchbar

I want to do a search in a tableview. But in this table view I work with a custom tableview Cell. So for the data part. I select in a view a categorie. Then in the next view I get all the products within this categorie. 
I followed a tutorial and implemented all the methods.

This is my function for getting the products.

```
-(void) fillArrayProducts:(NSString *)cat{
    NSMutableString *postString = [NSMutableString stringWithString:kGETProducts];
    [postString appendString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"?%@=%@",@"Pro_cat",cat]];
    [postString setString:[postString stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

    NSMutableURLRequest *request= [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:postString]];
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

    postConnection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self startImmediately:YES];

    NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:postString]];

    NSError *error;

    json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:kNilOptions error:&error];

   arrayProducts = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
   copyArrayProducts = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    arrayProductNaam = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    for (int i=0; i<[json count]; i++) {
        arrayProduct = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
        [arrayProduct addObject:[json objectAtIndex:i]];

        [arrayProducts addObject:arrayProduct];
        [arrayProductNaam addObject:[[[arrayProducts valueForKey:@"Pro_naam"] objectAtIndex:i]objectAtIndex:0]];
        [copyArrayProducts addObject:arrayProduct];
    } 
    NSDictionary *productsDict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:arrayProductNaam forKey:@"Products"];
    NSLog(@"%@",arrayProductNaam);

}
```

No what I'm doing. I have an array 'arrayProducts' in this array I put arrays from 'arrayProduct'. In arrayProduct you can find Pro_id,Pro_naam,Pro_prijs. But I only want to search on Pro_naam. So I fill also an array (arrayProductNaam) with only the products names.

So here is the part were I do my search.

```
- (void) searchTableView {

    NSString *searchText = searchbar.text;
    NSMutableArray *searchArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    for (NSDictionary *dictionary in arrayProductNaam)
    {
        NSArray *array = [dictionary objectForKey:@"Pro_naam"];
        [searchArray addObjectsFromArray:array];
    }

    for (NSString *sTemp in searchArray)
    {
        NSRange titleResultsRange = [sTemp rangeOfString:searchText options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch];

        if (titleResultsRange.length > 0)
            [copyArrayProducts addObject:sTemp];
    }
}
```

I think that it's here were I getting this error.

> 2012-02-02 13:22:40.958 MamzelBestelling2[23727:f803] -[__NSCFString
>   objectForKey:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x6c34780
>   2012-02-02 13:22:40.959 MamzelBestelling2[23727:f803] *** Terminating
>   app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason:
>   '-[__NSCFString objectForKey:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance
>   0x6c34780'

Answer (score 1):

You are not filling arrayProductNaam with Dictionary. Its filled by NSString. Now, in the searchTableView function you are handling these string members as Dictionaries and hence the problem.

Answer (score 0):

try to NSLog your String Array. so you can get the idea it exist or not

Comment: when i try a NSLog in my for loop, it doesn't print anything. but Just before my for loop it shows somewhat.

Comment: have you print your search text?

Comment: It crashes immediatly when I push one letter. But it also prints this letter in my nslog

Comment: try to run with break point and see where is exactly it crash. Also check your dictionary

Answer (score 0):

you are trying to get a keyValue from a string not from a dictionary.